# How to install Dazuko on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu

I want to use on-access scanning feature of clamav. But before that I must install Dazuko. My linux kernel is 3.16.1, but Dazuko can only be install on kernel version earlier than 2.6.5. I don't know how to solve this problem. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ubuntu has Documentation for this. Hope this might help you.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DazukoTroubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However, in this link , linux kernel version is too low , the situation is not consistent with my. T.T